# Date is ok in application, but saves with -2 hours to database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using MySQL, hibernate/JPA, and spring boot. I am receiving data from front end which are correct, even in my back end are totally correct, but when I save it to database, it saves with -2 hours. So when upload time is
2019-08-07 00:00 then in database its saved as: 2019-08-06 22:00

```
@Entity
public class Document {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    private String title;

    private String description;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "resource_path")
    private String resourcePath;

    @Column(name = "upload_datetime", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date uploadDatetime;

    @Column(name = "approval_end_time", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date approvalEndTime;

    @Column(name = "active_start_time", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date activeStartTime;

    @Column(name = "active_end_time", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date activeEndTime;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "document", cascade= CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<UsersDocuments> documentsForUsers = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;


Document document = new Document(title, desc);

        document.setUploadDatetime(new Date());

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");

        String strDate = dateFormat.format(document.getUploadDatetime());
        System.out.println("ULOAD " + strDate); // writes 2019-08-07 01:07:57, but saves -2h to db


        try {
            document.setApprovalEndTime(new Date());
            document.setActiveStartTime(formatter.parse(startOfReading));
            document.setActiveEndTime(formatter.parse(endOfReading));
        } catch (ParseException e){

        }

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
```

Comment: what is your sql version?

Comment: JPA stores dates etc. in UTC, times in your app are in your current (or servers) timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the timezone in the formatter.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of moving parts here, but the core of it will be that MySQL will store the data internally usually in UTC (can vary depending on engine used). When the client (your app or database query tool) connects it either declares it's timezone through the connection string or accepts the default of the server running the db. Most probably, either your app or your client are is declaring a timezone, the other is not which explains why the data appears different.

Have a look at useTimezone and serverTimezone connection parameters on the jdbc string or the settings of your MySQL client.